# Values of combobox with internal sheet name

Tags: excel, combobox, vba

I have an Excel spreadsheet in which I want to apply a combobox.
The values for the drop down of the combobox are shown in Column A in the Excel sheet:

```
            A
1        Test 1
2        Test 2
3        Test 3
4        Test 4
```

So far I use the following code for the combobox:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
ComboBox1.RowSource = "Sheet1!A1:A4"
End Sub
```

This code works perfectly. However, when I change the *name of the sheet* from "Sheet1" to for example "Marketing" the code won't run anymore. Therefore, preferable the code should refer to the **internal sheet** name in Excel.
Thus I created the following code:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
ComboBox1.RowSource = Sheet1.Range("A1:A4")
End Sub
```

However, with this code I get runtime error 424.
Do you have any idea how I can use the internal sheet name to get the values from the sheet into the drop down menu of the combobox?

Answer (score 1):

```
ComboBox1.RowSource = Sheet1.Name & "!A1:A4"
```

---

You can also add the range as a hidden Name, so that it auto updates (not tested):

```
ThisWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="myName", RefersTo:="=Sheet1!A1:A4", Visible:=False
```

and then in the UserForm:

```
ComboBox1.RowSource = "myName"
```